# How to use Net:SSH to upload file from server1 to server2

Tags: ruby, linux, scp

i have 3 web server : local server 0 ; remote server1 ;remote server2

i want to run local ruby script to upload file in server1 to server2;

how to do it? just use ruby.

i have tried shell util such as expect; it worded but how to use it in ruby?

i also tried

```
ssh =Net::SSH.start(host,username,:password => password) do |ssh|
      remote = Net::SSH.start(host,username,:password=>password)
      remote.exec!("mkdir -p path")
      result = ssh.exec!("scp local_path root@remote_host:remot_path")
      puts result
```

but this way needs to  add ssh_key in each remote web server

how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried so far. We won't write your code for you.

Comment: See, to do such things from server1 to server2 (copy files, DB connection, etc..) . You must have access to server2 from server1. After that everything will work simply.

Comment: Always be careful when executing shell commands to handle paths with irregular characters like space and `*` in them. [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) can do this for you.

Comment: Why can't you use `scp` normally? `scp remote1:/path/to/file remote2:/path/to/file`